# Is there any other method to avoid duplicate result by looping inside a looping python (not groupby/transform)?

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

i have 2 set of data and i would like to find and match by condition and i do not want my matched result to be repeated if have similar criteria.

data as below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date' : ['16-04-2020', '20-04-2020', '16-04-2020', '16-04-2020', '20-04-2020', '20-04-2020', '16-04-2020'],
                    'item' : ['X-317', 'ry-186', 'opq-468','999-xq','789-44','154-abc','opq-468'],
                    'no': ['36','55','45','77','107','1149','456' ],
                    'result':['','','','','','','']})


df_list = pd.DataFrame({'date' : ['16-04-2020', '16-04-2020', '16-04-2020', '20-04-2020', '16-04-2020', '16-04-2020', '20-04-2020'],
                        'item' : ['opq-468', 'ry-186','789-44','154-abc', 'opq-468','opq-468','123-x'],
                        'complete': ['yes','no','on-going','yes','yes','yes','no' ],
                        'code':['alpha', 'vertical','horizon','grand','empire','jade','roms']})
```

my intention is to **match date**, **complete = 'yes'** and **item in df is same as df_list**, but if there is similar from the result, it will proceed to find next one, then after that, if the index is not None or -1, i would use it in my next def

i have tried below:

```
for j in range(len(df)):
    def test():
        index=-1
        for i in range(len(df_list)):
            if ((df_list['date'][i] == df['date'][j] ) and (df_list['complete'][i] == 'yes') and (df_list['item'][i] == df['item'][j])):        
                index = i
        return index
    print(test())
      
    if test() != -1:
        .... (other def)
```

and my outcome for test() is [-1 -1 5 -1 -1 3 5] where the 5 is repeated

Expected **print(test())** should be:

```
         date     item    no result   **test()**
0  16-04-2020    X-317    36           -1
1  20-04-2020   ry-186    55           -1
2  16-04-2020  opq-468    45            0
3  16-04-2020   999-xq    77           -1
4  20-04-2020   789-44   107           -1
5  20-04-2020  154-abc  1149            3
6  16-04-2020  opq-468   456            4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have found a method using list and count, wish to know if there is another method, thanks

```
listrange = []
count = []
for j in range(len(df)):
    def test():
        index=-1
        for i in range(len(df_list)):
            if ((df_list['date'][i] == df['date'][j] ) and (df_list['complete'][i] == 'yes') and (df_list['item'][i] == df['item'][j]) and
                count.count(j) == listrange.count(i)):        
                listrange.append(i)
                count.append(j)
                index = i                              
        return index
    # print(test())
    if test() != -1:
        print(test())
```

Answer (score 0):

In my experience it more efficient to use pandas methods instead of loops and indexes.
You can bypass this problem by using pandas merge.

Below is the implementation of your intent.

> my intention is to match date, complete = 'yes' and item in df is same as df_list

pandas doc [pandas merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date' : ['16-04-2020', '20-04-2020', '16-04-2020', '16-04-2020', '20-04-2020', '20-04-2020', '16-04-2020'],
                     'item' : ['X-317', 'ry-186', 'opq-468','999-xq','789-44','154-abc','opq-468'],
                         'no': ['36','55','45','77','107','1149','456' ],
                          'result':['','','','','','','']})
     
   
df_list = pd.DataFrame({'date' : ['16-04-2020', '16-04-2020', '16-04-2020', '20-04-2020', '16-04-2020', '16-04-2020', '20-04-2020'],
                              'item' : ['opq-468', 'ry-186','789-44','154-abc', 'opq-468','opq-468','123-x'],
                             'complete': ['yes','no','on-going','yes','yes','yes','no' ],
                             'code':['alpha', 'vertical','horizon','grand','empire','jade','roms']})

res = df.merge(df_list, on=['date','item'], how='inner')

res[res['complete']=='yes']

Out[30]:

      date     item    no result complete    code
0  16-04-2020  opq-468    45             yes   alpha
1  16-04-2020  opq-468    45             yes  empire
2  16-04-2020  opq-468    45             yes    jade
3  16-04-2020  opq-468   456             yes   alpha
4  16-04-2020  opq-468   456             yes  empire
5  16-04-2020  opq-468   456             yes    jade
6  20-04-2020  154-abc  1149             yes   grand
```

Comment: merge method does not seem to be work as my real data count is more than thousands and i will more criteria when matching. and the result is not what i desire, thanks anyway